# Connect to openVPN Server

Tags: openvpn

i'm trying to setup a openVPN Server,

But then i trying to connect it says:

```
2019-07-21 13:21:44 OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-apple-darwin [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [MH/RECVDA] [AEAD] built on Nov 29 2018
2019-07-21 13:21:44 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018, LZO 2.10
2019-07-21 13:21:44 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:53549
2019-07-21 13:21:44 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
2019-07-21 13:21:44 *Tunnelblick: openvpnstart starting OpenVPN
2019-07-21 13:21:45 *Tunnelblick: Established communication with OpenVPN
2019-07-21 13:21:45 >INFO:OpenVPN Management Interface Version 1 -- type 'help' for more info
2019-07-21 13:21:45 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:53549
2019-07-21 13:21:45 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'pid'
2019-07-21 13:21:45 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'auth-retry interact'
2019-07-21 13:21:45 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
2019-07-21 13:21:45 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state'
2019-07-21 13:21:45 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 1'
2019-07-21 13:21:45 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
2019-07-21 13:21:45 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
2019-07-21 13:21:45 PLUGIN_INIT: POST /Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn/openvpn-2.4.6-openssl-1.0.2q/openvpn-down-root.so '[/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpn/openvpn-2.4.6-openssl-1.0.2q/openvpn-down-root.so] [/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/client.down.tunnelblick.sh] [-9] [-d] [-f] [-m] [-w] [-ptADGNWradsgnw]' intercepted=PLUGIN_UP|PLUGIN_DOWN 
2019-07-21 13:21:50 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'password [...]'
2019-07-21 13:21:50 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2019-07-21 13:21:50 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2019-07-21 13:21:50 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
2019-07-21 13:21:50 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1563708110,RESOLVE,,,,,,
2019-07-21 13:21:50 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:1194
2019-07-21 13:21:50 Socket Buffers: R=[786896->786896] S=[9216->9216]
2019-07-21 13:21:50 UDP link local: (not bound)
2019-07-21 13:21:50 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:1194
2019-07-21 13:21:50 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
2019-07-21 13:21:50 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1563708110,WAIT,,,,,,
```

i'm on Mac OS, and i'm useing Tunnelblick software

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

i found out i'm on 16.04 ubuntu.

i found this script here:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Nyr/openvpn-install/a6048d509fff11c28cbabc36633f76c1ac5ce988/openvpn-install.sh
```

That works for me :)